# Cufon & IE8 - Array Object Expected

Tags: javascript, cufon

I'm getting this error in IE8. Has anyone seen this before?

```
Webpage error details:
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)
Timestamp: Mon, 6 Dec 2010 19:31:00 UTC

Message: Array object expected
Line: 7
Char: 6559
Code: 0
URI: http://ideacity.smallparade.com/js/fonts/cufon-yui.js
```

Comment: How about posting some code to go along with the error message? Does it work on other browsers?

Comment: Works in other browsers. I switched from using the YUI version to an uncompressed file and narrowed it down to line 505, which is this: `this.add = function(key, args) { map[key] = list.push(args) - 1; };`

Comment: Narrowed it down further to find that it happens when I call this: `Cufon.replace($$('#section-tagline p'), {}, false);`. This is called because `$$('#section-tagline p')` often get's updated with Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is that `$$` coming from? You forgot to mention which libraries you're using besides Cufon.

Note that if you have content that changes, it's enough to use replace normally (just pass in a string of selectors), and then call `Cufon.refresh` after each change.

Comment: I'm using Mootools. I'd rather not refresh the entire page, though. Just the element being replaced.

Comment: @Brandon: I don't think `Cufon.refresh` will re-render elements that have already been replaced. All it does is it searches for elements matching the selectors that *haven't* been replaced yet (i.e. are new) and replaces those. Dynamic content is exactly what it's for.